# How to pick the value from ifPresent of Optional

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

How do I pick the value from the method `ifPresent`, as this method returns void?

The logic that I want to apply is: If the object `deliveryInfo` is not `null`, take the delivery quantity and set it into the object `dto`, but using Optional, without any null check.

```
Optional<TT021DeliveryCodingContainerDto> deliveryInfo =
    tt021OrderingBusinessHandler
        .getDeliveryCodingContainersByDeliveryAndOrderDetail(
            delivery.getId(), position.getOrderDetails().getId());
deliveryInfo.ifPresent(TT021DeliveryCodingContainerDto::getDeliveredQuantity);
dto.setQuantityDelivered(deliveredQuantity);
```

Comment: `getDeliveryCodingContainersByDeliveryAndOrderDetail`. Huh, that's a method name. You can check `orElse()`, `orElseGet()`, `orElseThrow()`. Or use `if(opt.isPresent()){T val = opt.get(); //do something with val}`

Comment: What is `deliveredQuantity`? Can you show how you would do this *without* Optional?

Comment: If I do if(opt.isPresent()){T val=opt.get()}, I don't see the benefit of this approach against using a normal null check

Comment: `Optional` does not make your *code cleaner* it is a hack to be used with older code. To make your code cleaner for new code, do not allow `null` anywhere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `deliveryInfo.ifPresent(i -> dto.setQuantityDelivered(i.getDeliveredQuantity());`?

If you want to return something from the method, use `map` instead of `ifPresent`; this will return another Optional wrapping the result (if any).

Answer (score 6):

Optional.ifPresent() is a terminal method that accepts a Consumer. Consumer is a function that takes some arguments and *consumes* them and returns nothing. You can pick the value from the argument used in lambda expression that is passed as a consumer.

```
Optional<TT021DeliveryCodingContainerDto> deliveryInfo =
tt021OrderingBusinessHandler
    .getDeliveryCodingContainersByDeliveryAndOrderDetail(
        delivery.getId(), position.getOrderDetails().getId());

deliveryInfo.map(info -> info.getDeliveredQuantity())
.ifPresent(quantity -> dto.setQuantityDelivered(quantity); // you can replace those with method references
```

Comment: Why do you call it terminal? It doesn't end anything.

Comment: @zeroflagL It ends the pipeline of operations on Optional monad

Comment: What pipeline? You can call `ifPresent` and after that any other of the Optional's method. It's not a `Stream` that's consumed eventually.

Comment: @zeroflagL because it has nothing to do with Stream's lazy evaluation. At some point you need to unwrap a value from a monadic context and do something with it. And this is what this method does. By "pipeline" I meant chain of monadic transformations

Comment: But you describe it like a stream, that's the point. And no: it doesn't unwrap the value. Following your logic `Collection.forEach` would be a terminal operation too. Java's `Optional` is not the sophisticated construct you seem to think it is. It's just a way to clearly communicate the absence of a result.

Comment: @zeroflagL Not really. I described it as a monad and your example has nothing to do with it. Optionals are only as sophisticated as other monads.